# SQL with multiple when have null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a query for retrieving data from two tables. The tables have data like this:

Table1:

```
StudentId Studentname
---------------------
1         test
2         test1
```

Table2:

```
StudentId Assignmentstatus date
--------------------------------------
1         0                 01/01/2014
1         1                 02/01/2014
```

status  1 means assignment submitted, 2 means returned after verification.

While joining the table

```
select 
    student.StudentId, student.Studentname,
    case (select top 1 Assignmentstatus 
          from Assignment 
          where Assignment.StudentId = student.StudentId 
          order by date desc) when 0 then 1 else 0 end as AssignmentSubmitted 
from 
    student 
left join 
    Assignment on Assignment.studentId = Student.StudentId.
```

It returns 1 for StudentId 2 also.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @DavidG would get zero for "AssignmentSubmitted" to studentid 2 and studentid 1.Now it returns one for studentid 2.

Comment: @wewesthemenace would get zero for "AssignmentSubmitted" to studentid 2 and studentid 1. Now it returns one for studentid 2.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is your query:

```
select s.StudentId, s.Studentname,
       (case (select top 1 Assignmentstatus
              from Assignment a2
              where a2.StudentId = s.StudentId
              order by date desc
             )
            when 0 then 1 else 0
        end) as AssignmentSubmitted 
from student s left join
     Assignment a 
     on a.studentId = s.StudentId;
```

The outer join to assignment is not necessary, so you probably really want:

```
select s.StudentId, s.Studentname,
       (case (select top 1 Assignmentstatus
              from Assignment a2
              where a2.StudentId = s.StudentId
              order by date desc
             )
            when 0 then 1 else 0
        end) as AssignmentSubmitted 
from student s;
```

Your inner join is comparing the most recent value of `AssignmentStatus` in `Assignment` for a given student to `0`.  For neither student is the most recent status 0.  In one case it is "1".  In the other "Null", so it will always return 0.  A SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29d5c/1).

Presumably, you want the status if available.  I would be inclined to write this query using `outer apply`:

```
select s.StudentId, s.Studentname, coalesce(a.Assignmentstatus, 0) as Assignmentsubmitted
from student s outer apply
     (select top 1 Assignmentstatus
      from Assignment a2
      where a2.StudentId = s.StudentId
      order by date desc
     ) a;
```

You can use a `case` instead of `coalesce()` if the actual logic is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a CASE statement. Instead you can replace `NULL` with `0` using [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
SELECT Student.StudentId,
       Student.Studentname,
       ISNULL(Assignment.AssignmentStatus, 0) AS AssignmentStatus
FROM Student 
LEFT JOIN Assignment
    ON Assignment.StudentId = Student.StudentId
```

Comment: If I have one more status '2' then I can't proceed with  ISNULL(Assignment.AssignmentStatus, 0) AS AssignmentStatus.Can you please have a  look

Answer (score 0):

It seems you that you want to get the latest Assignmentstatus to any Student, don't you?

How about like that?

```
select t1.Studentname, 
       t2.Assignmentstatus, 
       t2.date 
  from table1 t1, table2 t2
 where t1.StudentId = t2.StudentId 
   and t2.date = (Select max(date) from table2 where StudentId = t1.StudentId)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5af1a1/1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming AssignmentStatus only ever increases (e.g. doesn't ever go back to 'submitted' after being returned) then you could use something like:

```
SELECT s.StudentId
     , s.Studentname
     , ISNULL(MAX(a.AssignmentStatus), 0) AS AssignmentStatus
FROM Student s
     LEFT JOIN Assignment a ON a.StudentId = s.StudentId
group by s.StudentId, s.Studentname
```